# Mocking is not working to inner function where HTTPwrapper class method gets called

Tags: c#, mocking, nunit, moq, dotnet-httpclient

I am mocking one of the inner function before giving actual call to outer function.
I am mocking a httpwrpapper class method.
Problem is my mocked method doesn't return the response.
Below is the code entire code.

Httpwrapper class and method

```
public class HTTPClientWrapper: IHTTPClientWrapper
{    
  public async Task<T>PostAsync<T>(string url, object somepostobject)
  {
    T result = null;    
    using(var client = new HttpClient()) {
      var response = await client.PostAsync(apiUrl, postObject, new   JsonMediaTypeFormatter()).ConfigureAwait(false);

      response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

      await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ContinueWith((Task <string> x) =>{
        if (x.IsFaulted) throw x.Exception;

        result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(x.Result);

      });
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

Consuming method

```
public class Executor {
 public Executor(IHTTPClientWrapper httpClientWrapper)
 {
  _httpClientWrpper=httpClientWrapper;
 }

 public void SomeMethod()
 {
  string test="test";
  GetConfig();
  var response = _httpClientWrpper.PostAsync<PersonResponse>(url,postObject);
 }
}
```

want to write a unit test case for this method.

> public void SomeMethod()
> {
> string test="test";
> GetConfig();
> var response = _httpClientWrpper.PostAsync(url,postObject);
> }

I tried below, but at the time of actual invoking of method it is not produce/trigger the responce which I mocked

```
Mock<IHTTPClientWrapper> mockhttpClient =new Mock<IHTTPClientWrapper>();
    
mockhttpClient.setup(t=>t.PostAsync<PersonResponse>(It.IsAny<string>(),It.IsAny<string>()).Returns(Task.FromResult<PersonResponse>(mockresponse));

mockexecutor.object.SomeMethod(someparametrs);
```

Comment: Are you using [this pkg](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HttpClientWrapper) for `HttpClientWrapper`?

Comment: This is not like a package I just created a class with this name : HttpClientWrapper and added a httpclient functionality into this.

Comment: Ohh okay, after your code update, now it is clearer.

Comment: yeah sorry for that i updated at last momment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: You should not mock your to be tested code.

---

```
mockexecutor.object.SomeMethod(someparametrs);
```

This line suggests me that you try to call the `SomeMethod` on a mocked object.

Whenever we are talking about mocking then we should **mock only the dependencies** of the system under test (or in short sut).

So, in your case you should mock the `IHTTPClientWrapper`, but not the `Executor`

```cs
//Arrange
var mockHttpClient =new Mock<IHTTPClientWrapper>();
mockHttpClient
   .Setup(client => ...)
   .ReturnsAsync(...);


var sut = new Executor(mockHttpClient.Object);

//Act
sut.SomeMethod();

//Assert
...
```

Comment: Thats worked like a charm, I missed these two steps : var sut = new Executor(mockHttpClient.Object);

//Act
sut.SomeMethod();

Comment: I'm glad that we could solve your issue quite quickly :D